# How to loop menu choice validation in python?

Tags: python, loops, validation, menu

I am trying to make a loop to validate my menu choices to be integers, but receiving this error when inputting letters`line 138, in <module> option = int(input("Enter your option:")) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'` . Sorry if code is a mess only been doing python for 2 weeks approx so still learning.
Ideally I would like the validation to also limit the choice to the 1-6 range for the choices.
P.S. I know it's wrong, but I just don't know what.
This is my code:

```
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Display Inventory')
    print('(5) Search for Item')
    print('(6) Quit')

#Selecting menu option
menu()
option = int(input("Enter your option:"))
while option !=0:
    if option == 1:
        addInventory()
    elif option == 2:
        removeInventory()
    elif option == 3:
        updateInventory()
    elif option == 4:
        printInventory()
    elif option == 5:
        searchItem()
    elif option == 6:
        answer = input("Are you sure you want to quit? Y/N: ")
        if answer == 'Y':
            exit()
        else:
            menu()
            option = (input("Enter your option:"))
    else:
        if option.isdigit():
            pass
        else:
            print("Enter a valid option: ")
    menu()
    option = int(input("Enter your option:"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
option = input("Enter your option:")

while not option.isdigit():
   option = input("Enter a valid option:")

option = int(option)
```

Also you can check if the number is in a certain range:

```
option = input("Enter your option:")

while not option.isdigit() or int(option) < 1 or int(option) > 6:
    option = input("Enter a valid option:")

option = int(option)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your call to `int()` in a try-except block. This way if an error is thrown, you can handle it. Like this:

```
# ... code ...
option = 0
try:
    option = int(input("Enter your option:"))
except ValueError:
    print("That is not a valid integer")
# ... code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem does not come rather from your code but from the type of data you are entering, by putting int() you are telling the input that the type of data you are going to receive is integer / int, check again if you are entering it well

Comment: "by putting int() you are telling the input that the type of data you are going to receive is intege" - well, no. `input` doesn't care about what you can do with its output, so `int` doesn't tell it anything. `int` tries to convert the *string* returned by `input`, that's all. If it represents a valid integer, it returns an `int` with this value. If it doesn't, it raises an exception (`ValueError`).